# Javascript function help

Tags: javascript

Can someone please look at this javascript function and tell me tell me what I am doing wrong? I want to pass in 4 variables. I know very little javascript.

Thanks.

```
  function chg(back,front,left,right)
  {
      return test("div#post", "#" + "back", "#" + "front", left, right);
  }
```

---

Here is the onload file

```
window.onload = function() {
  function chg(back,front,left,right)
  {
      return test("div#post", "#" + "back", "#" + "front", "left", "right");
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more information than that. Specifically, what you're trying to do, what the expected result is, what you're getting instead.

Comment: I'd suggest explaining what it is you're trying to accomplish (where are the variable coming from, where are they going and what are you tryng to do to them), offer the error message (or whatever message/result that suggests you're doing it wrong) and link to a demo page if at all possible.

Comment: I want to use this function to change my values dynamically. This is part of an onload event and is in a seperate file. I use an inline script tag in the file to call this onload file.

Comment: You need to show how you're calling the function. As is, you're only showing the function declaration, which does nothing but declare the function. In the second example, the function is private to the scope of the anonymous onload event handler. So the only way to call it is from window.onload(back, front, left, right) which is probably not what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is syntactically wrong that I can see.

- Did you mean `back` instead of `"back"`? ( same with front )
- Is there a `test` function defined in an outer scope? What does it return?
- Are the 4 arguments being populated?
- Can you provide more code?

Comment: Yes there is a test function in another file. Here is how I have this working now. This test function is in a file that handles all of the onLoad events. The reason that I want to put this into a function is so that I can dynamically change the colors and padding. Now I'm wondering if because this is an onload even that I can't do this. Is this possible? BTW: thank for the help.

Comment: you will not get a definitive answer without posting actual real code.

Comment: When are you calling `chg`? Where is `test` defined? Did you mean `back` instead of `"back"`? Did you read anything I wrote in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

For all intents and purposes, my code and your code do the exact same thing. Maybe this will help?

```
  function chg(back,front,left,right)
  {
      var result;

      //Pass left & right to the test function
      result = test("div#post", "#back", "#front", left, right);

      //Do something with back & front....
      //What?... I have no idea.

      return result;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Jimmy. I'm not a javascript guy by any means and maybe the problem is the "back" and "front" variables but as far as I thought, the test function is accepting them. I don't see a need for a return either. Am I wrong?

Comment: Like I said, my code and your code do the exact same thing.  If you don't see a need for a return, you should take a second look at your code.  Try telling us in words what you are trying to do.  For example "I want to dynamically set the height, width and position of a div onload"

Answer (score 0):

You have done nothing wrong syntactically. However, two of your input arguments (`back` and `front`) are never used - you are putting the words "back" and "front" in a string literal, so those arguments are never used. Functionally, it's impossible to say. What is `test()`? Is it another function declared elsewhere? If so, it would be helpful to see that one too.

Comment: Hi Rex, thanks for the help. Let me ask this. Can this function be used dynamically in an onload situation? I want to change these values on the fly.

Comment: It's hard to tell with this amount of context, but there should be no reason why not.